# Solve for x without a calculator

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Solve for values of $x$ without a calculator:

$x^2 - 2x - \cos x=0$

Comment: Is the equation $x^2-2x-\cos(x)=0$?

Comment: Typeset it with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and $\LaTeX$ to ensure your equation is read correctly.  Compare how $x^2$ looks compared to x 2.

Comment: To prevent from closing please show your effort and possible solutions. Please clarify that whether this a homework?

Comment: That said, just because certain questions may be easy to write does not make them easy to solve.  Mixing trig functions and polynomials, or polynomials and exponentials, etc..., can very quickly take the solutions outside of the realm of elementary functions.  At that point you might be lucky enough to have a named non-elementary function you can use such as the Lambert W function, however more often than not you just need to satisfy yourself with approximations.  This would appear to be the latter case.

Comment: Try using Newtons method which states that $$x_{1}=x_0-\frac{f^{'}(x_0)}{f(x_0)}$$ to approximate a solution.

Comment: Yes i was given this question and the teacher told me to solve the values of x by equating it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are x=-0.38772212... and x=+1.850717... as shown in [A197842](https://oeis.org/A197842)

Answer (score 1):

It is a transcendental equation, can be solved only numerically by methods such as Newton-Raphson, in a calculator.

Graphs of

$$ y= \cos x, \quad y=- 2x+x^2\;$$

show  approximate values of roots/solutions at their intersections.